# PHP: A way to sort through a loop and exclude certain entries after the query

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a system that displays items from a database table, dependant on if they are available.

I have two tables:

Reservations:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| ResID | CarID | UserID | startTime | startDate | endTime | endDate  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   4   |    4   | 13:00:00  |2013-04-21 |13:00:00 |2013-04-29|
```

And Cars:

```
-------------------------------------------
| CarID  |  make | model | serial | image |
-------------------------------------------
|   1    | Honda | civic | ky675  | 1.png |
```

So when a user visits a page, they input a start date and end date, a list of cars is then displayed after a query is ran to check if the car is available on that date.

So I came up with this query.

```
$carstring = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars 
                            {$statement} 
                            AND deleted = 'no' 
                            AND carID NOT IN (
                              SELECT carID FROM reservations 
                                WHERE startDate = '".$sqlcoldate."'
                            ) 
                          GROUP BY model");
```

What this does is select all cars from the database, it then however excludes the array of carIDs that are the array result from the sub-query. The remainder cars, it groups by model and displays them in a loop like so:

```
$getcars = $carstring;
while($searchcars = mysql_fetch_array($getcars)) {

 **some HTML showing car imag and make etc etc**

 }
```

This 'works'. As in, if I had 5 Honda Civics, and all of them were reserved on the dates the user had entered, their carIDs would be excluded from the loop. However it would not show the Honda Civic in the list at all, because all of them would be gone.

I need a way to tell if I run out of a certain model of car on a certain date. So I have three Civics, I know three are excluded, so I display one but it is not available to book.

I think the solution is to remove the sub-query. So First I run:

```
$nonavail = mysql_query("SELECT carID FROM reservations 
                         WHERE startDate = '".$sqlcoldate."'");
while($noavailrow = mysql_fetch_array($nonavail)) {
```

This gives me an array of carIDs I need to exclude, then I can grab all cars and sorth them using PHP and my carIDs. But I'm lost now...

Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: do not use `mysql_*` it is old. and we do not like old functions.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is what you want your new query to produce. Could you post a sample of the expected output?

Comment: SELECT based on model,make, left join available cars (do check the enddate though), group by model / make, count() available (or 0 if the left join results is NULL). All in 1 query, even your sorting can be done in this query.

Comment: @Wrikken that sounds promising. Although I am unsure about the count element, it will count them by model and be able to check if they are all gone?

Comment: too long to read... ;)

Answer (score 7):

It should be possible to do it like this:

```
SELECT    c.make, c.model, count(c.carid) - count(x.resid) available_cars
FROM      cars c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT   r.carid, r.resid
   FROM     reservations r 
   WHERE    ? BETWEEN r.startdate AND r.enddate) x ON x.carid = c.carid
WHERE     c.deleted = 'no'
GROUP BY  c.make, c.model
ORDER BY  c.make, c.model
```

The inner subquery will select only those reservations with start time before and end time after the given time (indicated by `?`). The outer query then selects all the cars and tries to find a reservation that belongs to each car (there can be one or none, but never more than one, because I guess you can't have several reservations for the same car at the same time). Finally the resultset is grouped by `make` and `model` and for each the number of cars in total and the number of reservations is calculated and the difference is the number of available cars.

This approach makes use of the fact that `COUNT()` does only count values that are **not** `NULL`.

Comment: Warning: This query with millions of rows will take minutes to run. Just something to be aware of

Comment: I am not sure about the use of _only_one_ time comparison parameter. Suppose I want to block cars between 4-7 PM. Now I cannot get cars that have already been reserved for 3-5 PM  (not available till 5 PM)  or 6-8 PM (only free at 7 PM).  As per above criteria, both these cases would be flagged as "available". Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well...the question uses only one date parameter, so I assumed that's what is needed. I do realize that it appears to be a rather strange use-case, but I won't start to second-guess questions. ;) And yes...the query will probably not be the fastest one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer up a PHP solution. SQL is probably the better performing option so this is really just to add some variety to the thread.

Here is how I understand the problem. You want to show the cars that are available AND at least one car for each model that is not available. ie:

- Ford Taurus - Available
- Ford Taurus - Available
- Honda Civic - Unavailable
- Hundai Sonata - Avaialble

...

```
// Keep track of the models so we know which ones we have already processed
$models = array();

// Filter the array of results
array_filter( $results, function ( $result ) use ( &$models )
{
    // If the model has not yet been represented, add the model to the models 
    // array and return true, preserving this item in the array
    if ( !in_array( $result->model, $models )
    {
        $models[] = $result->model;
        return true;
    }

    // If the car is in the excluded list, remove this item from the array
    if ( in_array( $result->car_id, $excluded_car_ids ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Im unsure how to tie this in with my current code and test it out?

Comment: @Bohdi #1) select md5(contact(make,model)) from cars ; #2) load the resultset into an array A - that gives you md5 hash of all make + model #3) when you are printing available cars - use PHP to store md5(make.model) into array B #4) after printing all available cars, iterate over A and look for entries that are not in B

Answer (score 0):

This query checks to see if the start or end date of a reservation happens during the period that a new customer desires a car. It sums the cars that are available.

```
SELECT c.model, ... ,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN (r.startDate BETWEEN $desiredstart AND $desiredend) OR
              (r.endData BETWEEN $desiredstart AND $desiredend)  
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1 END) as num_available
FROM cars c 
  LEFT JOIN reservations r 
  ON (c.CarID=r.CarID)
WHERE
  r.deleted = 'no' (
    SELECT carID FROM reservations 
       WHERE 
         AND
 ) 
GROUP BY c.model
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your "master list" of makes and models, and then left-join in what's available. This might not be the most optimized syntax, but it's pretty clear:

```
select Models.*, Available.* from (select make, model from Cars 
GROUP BY make, model) as Models
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE CarID NOT IN (1,3,6)) as Available on Models.model = Available.model
```

You'll notice that I removed the logic that excludes the reserved cars and replaced it with the NOT IN for testing purposes. But it's easy enough for you to plug it back in.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/266db/12/0

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem to solve.

First, you have to understand you're looking for a Not reserved car in a database containing your reserved cars...

You're looking for information that IS NOT in you database!
But you can deduct it from what you've got.

To simplify the comparison challenge, you should join your date and time (in your reservation table and in the two user criterias -start and end-) to a "timestamp" format... It will be easier to compare all your existing reservations to the user request.
see: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj27620.html for format info.

So you have to look for your reserved cars using your user data (start and end timestamps) and filter them OUT of all your possible cars.

                  UserStart        UserEnd
                         |                      |
case A  |------|   |                      |
case B           |--|--------|           |
case C              |   |----------|     |
case D              |            |-------|---|
case E              |                      |      |----------|
case F   |--------|------------------|----------------|
                         |                      |


You want cases A and E.

This script should find out cases B,C,D and F... And place all the CarIDs into an array I called "NotAvaibleCars".
It forgets about cases A and E (past/finished reservations and future reservations).

Then, you have to check, for each cars, if its ID is "inArray" before to show it on your result page.

Code:

```
$allReservedCars = mysql_query("SELECT * from reservation") or die(mysql_error());

$allCars = mysql_query("SELECT * from cars") or die(mysql_error());

$NotAvailableCars = array();

$userStart = $_POST['yourClientStartCriteria'];
$userEnd = $_POST['yourClientEndCriteria'];

while ($allCarsCheck = mysql_fetch_array($allReservedCars)){
$TimestampStart = $allCarsCheck['startDate'] . ' ' . $allCarsCheck['startTime'];
$TimestampEnd = $allCarsCheck['startDate'] . ' ' .$allCarsCheck['startTime'];

if (
    (($TimestampStart>$userStart)&&($TimestampStart<$userEnd)) ||   // if cases C or D (A reservation start already exist for this car between userStart and userEnd)
    (($TimestampEnd>$userStart)&&($TimestampEnd<$userEnd)) ||       // if case B or C (A reservation end already exist for this car between userStart and userEnd)
    (($TimestampStart<$userStart)&&($TimestampEnd>$userEnd))        // if case F (A reservation that wraps userStart and userEnd already exist for this car)
   ) {

   array_push($NotAvailableCars, $allCarsCheck['CarID']); // You have now an array of the NOT available cars.

   }

}


while($searchcars = mysql_fetch_array($allcars)) {

 if (inArray($searchcars['CarID'],$NotAvailableCars)){
  //Do nothing!
 }
 else{
 // Your code to show this available car.
 }
}
```

;)


Okay... I'm reading my solution again 8 hours later...
And I see that I missed the main question: To show something when there is no car available for a make/model combinaison.

I worked on it... And have a... Kind of a solution.
But I hope there is a better one... This all I can see for now.

```
$distinctMakeModel = mysql_query("SELECT distinct make, model from cars");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($distinctMakeModel)){
  array_push($CarModelArray, $row['make'] . ' -splitter- ' . $row['model']) // Array with all make/model combination

}

$CarQtyArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<$CarModelArray.length;$i++){
  $thisCar = explode(' -splitter- ',$carModelArray[$i]);

  $ThisCarQty = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from cars where make=$thisCar[0] AND model=$thisCar[1]");
  $thiscar = mysql_fetch_array($ThisCarQty);
  array_push($CarQtyArray, $thiscar[0];     //So now you have an array of quantity with indexes matching the $carModelArray indexes.
}
```

You now have an array of car make/model and an array of quantity with matching indexes.

The next chunk of code will create an array of unavailable quantity with the same matching indexes.

```
for($i=0;$i<$CarModelArray.length;$i++){
  $thisCar = explode(' -splitter- ',$carModelArray[$i]);
  $NotAvailableCarQtyArray[$i] = 0;

  for($j=0;$j<$NotAvailableCars.length;$j++){
    $thisNotAvailable = mysql_query("Select count(*) where make=$thisCar[$i] AND model=$thisCar[$i] AND carID=$NotAvailableCars[$j]");
    $isThisTheModel = mysql_fetch_array($thisNotAvailable);
    if ($isThisTheModel<>'0'){
      $NotAvailableCarQtyArray[$i] ++;
    }

  }
}
```

So now...
in $CarModelArray[0], lets say you have Honda Civic.
in $CarQtyArray[0], you have 3.
in $NotAvailableCarQtyArray[0], you have 3 (all gone!).

```
for ($i=0;$i<$CarModelArray.length;$i++){
  if ($CarQtyArray[$i]==$NotAvailableCarQtyArray[$i]){
    echo $CarModelArray[$i] . ' are not available.<br>';
  }
}
```

This takes waaayyy to many queries here!!!
It is not supposed to be a great idea to put a SQL query into a loop.
But, again... I don't see how to do otherwise.

It's like the amount of cars out between Start and End search multiplied by the amount of make/model you have.

But it should work...
At least I tried.
 ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$carstring = mysql_query("SELECT *,(SELECT count(CarID) FROM reservations WHERE reservations.CarID=cars.CarID AND '".$sqlcoldate."' NOT BETWEEN startDate AND endDate ) as availability FROM cars {$statement} AND deleted = 'no' GROUP BY model");
```

The query above will give you the list of cars with an additional field(availability) carrying the number of cars of a particular model available,if the car is not available the field will just display zero.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to get list of available cars and a list of unavailable car branches grouped by 'make' and 'mode' (for ex: Honda Civid, Ford Escape). So I think you are right to make 2 queries but the second query seems to be not right.

The first query is your first query which cannot retrieve unavailable cars.

The second query is get all cars unavailable group by 'make' and 'model'. This query looks like : `$nonavail = mysql_query("SELECT carID FROM reservations 
                         WHERE startDate = '".$sqlcoldate."' GROUP BY 'make', 'type'");`

After getting 2 arrays, you can manipulate and show them on layout properly. Keep in mind that the first is available cars, the second is unavailable car branch.

Answer (score 0):

Here give the solution for seperate the cars list available and unavailable for reservation.its very useful for you.

get the available cars list for reservation. ie).**reservation available for particular date interval..**

```
select *,'available' as status from cars where CarID not in(SELECT CarID FROM reservations
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( startDate,  ' ', startTime ) ) <= $startTimestamp
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( endDate,  ' ', endTime ) ) >= $endTimestamp)WHERE deleted = 'no' group by make,model order by make,model asc
```

get the not available cars list for reservation. ie).**already reserved for the particular date interval..**

```
select *,'not available' as status from cars where CarID not in(SELECT CarID FROM reservations
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( startDate,  ' ', startTime ) ) <= $startTimestamp
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( endDate,  ' ', endTime ) ) >= $endTimestamp)WHERE deleted = 'no' group by make,model order by make,model asc
```

note: convert the date to the timestamp format..

```
$startDateTime="21/04/2013 13:00:00"; //date example
list($sDay, $sMonth, $sYear, $sHour, $sMinute,$sSeconds) = split('[/ :]', $startDateTime); 
$startTimestamp=mktime($sHour, $sMinute,$sSeconds, $sMonth, $sDay, $sYear);

$endDateTime="29/04/2013 13:00:00"; //date example
list($eDay, $eMonth, $eYear, $eHour, $eMinute,$eSeconds) = split('[/ :]', $endDateTime); 
$endTimestamp=mktime($eHour, $eMinute,$eSeconds, $eMonth, $eDay, $eYear);
```

and the code is given below:

```
<?php
$startDateTime="21/04/2013 13:00:00"; //date example
list($sDay, $sMonth, $sYear, $sHour, $sMinute,$sSeconds) = split('[/ :]', $startDateTime); 
$startTimestamp=mktime($sHour, $sMinute,$sSeconds, $sMonth, $sDay, $sYear);

$endDateTime="29/04/2013 13:00:00"; //date example
list($eDay, $eMonth, $eYear, $eHour, $eMinute,$eSeconds) = split('[/ :]', $endDateTime); 
$endTimestamp=mktime($eHour, $eMinute,$eSeconds, $eMonth, $eDay, $eYear);

$carstringAvailable = mysql_query("select *,'available' as status from cars 
                            WHERE CarID not in(
                                SELECT CarID FROM reservations
                                WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( startDate,  ' ', startTime ) ) <= $start_Timestamp
                                  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( endDate,  ' ', endTime ) ) >= $end_Timestamp
                                  )
                            AND deleted = 'no' group by make,model order by make,model asc");

$getcarsAvailable = $carstringAvailable;
?>
<h3>Available cars for reservation</h3>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>CarID</th><th>make</th><th>model</th><th>serial</th><th>image</th><th>status</th>
</tr>
<?php 
if(mysql_num_rows($getcarsAvailable)>0)
{
    while($searchcarsAvail = mysql_fetch_array($getcarsAvailable)) 
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsAvail['CarID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsAvail['make'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsAvail['model'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsAvail['serial'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsAvail['image'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsAvail['status'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    } 
}
else 
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'>No records found</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>

<?php 
$carstringUnAvailable = mysql_query("select *,'available' as status from cars 
                            WHERE CarID in(
                                SELECT CarID FROM reservations
                                WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( startDate,  ' ', startTime ) ) <= $start_Timestamp
                                  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( endDate,  ' ', endTime ) ) >= $end_Timestamp
                                  )
                            AND deleted = 'no' group by make,model order by make,model asc");

$getcarsUnAvailable = $carstringUnAvailable;
?>
<h3>Already Reserved cars list</h3>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>CarID</th><th>make</th><th>model</th><th>serial</th><th>image</th><th>status</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($getcarsUnAvailable)>0)
{ 
    while($searchcarsUnAvail = mysql_fetch_array($getcarsUnAvailable)) 
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsUnAvail['CarID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsUnAvail['make'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsUnAvail['model'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsUnAvail['serial'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsUnAvail['image'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $searchcarsUnAvail['status'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    }
 }
 else 
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='5'>No records found</td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
```